# How to properly submit a dask written script with SLURM

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I'm using a dask launching a for loop over several nodes. The problème is that I'm not sure how to properly send the job with SLURM

I can launch it properly from the login node but i've been warned that it uses to much memory and then to submit a job. The problem is that when i submit a job dask can't submit the jobs since it doensn't have the access from the computing node resulting to the error : sbatch: `error: Batch job submission failed: Access/permission denied`

My code looks like :

```
somefunc(n):
    try:
        long calculation
        return result
    except:
         return to be filtered result

def main():
    num_image = 268828
    X = np.empty((num_image,7), dtype=np.float32)
    cluster = SLURMCluster(cores=32,
                           processes=32,
                           interface ="ib0",
                           walltime="04:10:00",
                           memory = "80GB")
    cluster.scale(600)
    client = Client(cluster)

    with tqdm (total = num_image) as pbar:
        future = client.map(somefunc, range(num_image))
        for future,result in as_completed(future,with_results = True):
            X[result[0],:] = result
            pbar.update(1)
            future.release()

    return X


if __name__ == '__main__':

    x = main()
    io.savemat('/gpfs/home/savedata.mat', {'data': x})
```

And my job file is simply :

```
conda activate my_env
python my_code.py
```

so it asks for only one node (why i should only need to pass the informations to the sheduler)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> error: Batch job submission failed: Access/permission denied

This is likely an issue that is specific to your cluster.  I recommend asking your system administrators for help. You will likely need to give them the full traceback.

For an example of common issues, I recommend this blogpost:  https://blog.dask.org/2019/08/28/dask-on-summit